# Body is un-real and only atma is real in Hinduism?

Tags: atma, maya, advaita

Almost all concepts in *non-dualism(advaita-siddhanta)*, it is believed that Human body is unreal or *"maya"* and only ***atma***  is real. Their claim is that without atma body is nothing. In my personal opinion, that is completely illogical concept. Because, if we think vice-versa, ***atma*** is nothing without the body. The identity of atma is only in living bodies else it is nothing, even weaker than an atom.

Are my thoughts right? If not, please explain with clarifications. Is ***body*** really ***unreal*** and weaker than ***atma***?

Comment: who said you that atman is an atom. It is more than atom have you heard about Brain as a neurocomputer, and atman as a quantum consious in it's physical form in body? see this article for more details http://www.quantumconsciousness.org/documents/cogscipub.pdf

Comment: @creator - i didn't told like that. Please read again my question.

Comment: What do you mean by liking truth is truth if you believe that anu atom is the eternal one believe it but actually atman is a conscious part of Supreme Consciousness.

Answer (score 6):

No your thought is not right, **Atma**(soul) is part of parmatma(the supreme soul), hence it is pure. Atma is unborn, it can't be killed and Eternal. Atma is free and unbound, it gets a new body in every life.

**Body** is made of five Tattvas i.e. *Earth, Water, Fire, Air and Ether* and is bound to all these. Your body dies after death which is not true for atma.

Posting following shloks from Bhagwat Geeta Adhyay 2 for reference

> - [BG 2.17](http://vedabase.com/bg/2/17/en) : That which pervades the entire body you should know to be indestructible. No one is able to destroy that imperishable
>     soul.
> - [BG 2.20](http://vedabase.com/bg/2/20/en) : For the soul there is neither birth nor death at any time. He has not come into being, does not come into being, and will
>     not come into being. He is unborn, eternal, ever-existing and
>     primeval. He is not slain when the body is slain.
> - [BG 2.21](http://vedabase.com/bg/2/21/en) : O Pārtha, how can a person who knows that the soul is indestructible, eternal, unborn and immutable kill anyone or cause
>     anyone to kill?
> - [BG 2.22](http://vedabase.com/bg/2/22/en) : As a person puts on new garments, giving up old ones, the soul similarly accepts new material bodies, giving up the old and
>     useless ones.
> - [BG 2.23](http://vedabase.com/bg/2/23/en) : The soul can never be cut to pieces by any weapon, nor burned by fire, nor moistened by water, nor withered by the wind.
> - [BG 2.24](http://vedabase.com/bg/2/24/en) : This individual soul is unbreakable and insoluble, and can be neither burned nor dried. He is everlasting, present
>     everywhere, unchangeable, immovable and eternally the same.
> - [BG 2.25](http://vedabase.com/bg/2/25/en) : It is said that the soul is invisible, inconceivable and immutable. Knowing this, you should not grieve for the body.

Answer (score 5):

No, that's not the sole view in Hinduism. As you have stated, that is the view of the Advaita Vedantins, the school of thought preached by Shankaracharya. As per them, the whole of our existence including the body, *atma* (individual soul), etc. are illusion and unreal; Brahman alone is only real. They do not even acknowledge that *jiva* is different from Brahman. So their tenet is:

> *brahma satyam jagat mithya, jivo brahmaiva naparah*
>   -Brahman is real, the world is unreal. *Jiva* is Brahman itself, not different.

But as per other schools of thought, the world and the body are not unreal, but temporary. And   soul is the ever existing permanent entity. Because body is subject to birth and death, but the soul is not, the soul is considered as the actual identity of a *jiva* and given more importance.

## Atma is nothing without the body?

The view that *atma* is nothing withou the body is incorrect. It is because the body has a dependent existence, but the *atma* does not. You said this because you feel *atma* has no identity without the body. But the truth is, *atma* has no identity irrespective of whether it is in the body or not. *Atma* itself is devoid of material name, form and quality. So doesn't matter whether it stays in the body or not, it always maintains its true identity of no identity. It means, even if the body doesn't exist, *atma* will not lose any of its inherent quality and existence. Cessation of body doesn't have any impact upon *atma*. It is because *atma* stays in the body untouched by it just like the all pervading sky:

> *yathā sarva-gataṁ saukṣmyād ākāśaṁ nopalipyate
>
>   sarvatrāvasthito dehe tathātmā nopalipyate* [BG - 13.33]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Like the all pervading subtle space doesn’t mix with anything, so also the soul situated throughout the body doesn’t get mixed.

But if the *atma* ceases to exist, then the body will become dead and lose all its features like liveliness, growth, activity, etc. So **because body is depended upon the *atma*, but not *atma* on the body, it is the *atma* which is superior.**

Now the thing is, neither the *atma*, nor the body can alone give rise to any sensible meaning. Both has to be present together for existence to exist. But existence is not eternal, it will dissolute one day. Hence, all meaning will be gone. There will be no one else to ponder over whether body or the *atma* is greater. In that state when nothing existed, it is *atma* alone that existed:

> *ātmā vā idameka evāgra āsīt* [Ait. Up. - 1.1.1]
>   - *Atma* alone was present in the beginning.

For these reasons, *atma* being independent, is superior. And body (product of *prakruti*) being necessary for a meaningful existence is real but temporary.

Comment: @@behappy- Even, advaitins cant/dont say atman is illusion. Can, you provide any proof from Shankaras prasthatraya where he explicitly states, that Atma is Illusion

Comment: @Krishna If you see I have "individual soul" in brackets beside *atma*, so I mean individual souls are unreal, there is only one *atma*.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have very gross misunderstanding. Body, material body specifically is not the real identiy of atma or soul. In fact whole teachings of Hinduism primarily focus on how to develop lesser attachment with our material bodies and more on the real self, the atma, which is the essense of an individual because attachment to the material bodies keep us earth bound and we will never be serious about liberation from this existence of pain and suffering. The physical body is iving because it is made animate by atma. As soon as the soul leaves the body it is no better than mound of dust.

Answer (score -1):

Let me tell you something. Please pay attention. We are here from the beginning of the universe. Our Atma is eternal or Amar. Our body is like a dress that we wear. Every birth, we wear a dress and when we die, we leave the dress or open the dress. Now, you would be thinking what happens after death. Well, all our karma is counted, bad or evil, good or bad etc. The Atma never ever dies. When we have enough good karma or we have realised the purpose of our birth, the Atma gets promoted to a higher dimension or what many say heaven. We get mukti or moksha

Comment: You should cite sources.